# Local coordinates on a product of two manifolds.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Let $X, Y$ be two manifolds. Let $(U, x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ and $(V, y_1, \ldots, y_m)$ local coordinates of $X, Y$ respectively. I think that a local coordinate on $X 
\times Y$ is $(U \times V, x_1 \otimes y_1, \ldots, x_n \otimes y_m)$. Is this correct? Thank ou very much.

Comment: What is that even meant to mean when $n \ne m$? The correct expression is even simpler - think about what the dimension of $X \times Y$ should be. Remember, the product of manifolds is the cartesian product of underlying sets, so it should be modelled on the direct sum of Euclidean spaces, not the tensor product.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis, thank you very much. Is $(U \times V, x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n, y_1, \ldots, y_m)$ a local coordinate on $X \times Y$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll do the case $n=m=1$ for ease of notation (nevermind the fact that all manifolds of dimension one are $S^1$...)

Let $X$ and $Y$ be the manifolds, and let $(U,x)$ be a local coordinate on $X$, and $(V,y)$ a local coordinate on $Y$ (this is by definition a homeomorphism $V \to \mathbb R$).

Then the charts on $X \times Y$ are given by all combinations of $x\times y: U \times V \to \mathbb R \times \mathbb R$. The map is $(a,b) \mapsto \left( x(a),y(b) \right)$.